# Does the unevaluated pointer in a conditional expression, turns void?

Tags: c, pointers, conditional-operator

This [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Conditional-Expressions) says that the second and third operands in a conditional expression must be of compatible types. It also says that one of the second and third pointer operands might be `NULL`. So does that mean the unevaluated pointer turns `NULL`?

Example: `a == a? pointer1 : pointer2;`

Hear `a == a` is true so `pointer1` gets evaluated and `pointer2` is left unevaluated. So, is that the `pointer2` which turns `NULL`.

Comment: It doesn't say that the pointer will *turn* `NULL` it says *"pointers to compatible types (one of which might be the `NULL` pointer)"*

Comment: Nothing "turns null". It just says that if you want you can write `NULL` as one of the operands.

Comment: `test ? condition true : condition false` is a *ternary operator*. `a == a` will always test `true` even if `a = 0;` (or `NULL`) so the result will always be `pointer1`. But, `a` (and all variables) *must be initialized* before you attempt to access its value. So if you simply have `int a; a == a ? pointer1 : pointer2;` you invoke *Undefined Behavior*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So does that mean the unevaluated pointer turns NULL?

No it explains exception where second and third operands can have different types. One of them can be `NULL`.

```
int * pointer = (1 == 1) ? NULL : &intvar;
```

or

```
int * pointer = (1 == 1) ? &intvar : NULL;
```

Becouse one of them is `int*` and second `void*`.

---

You think that in this case

```
int * pointer = (1 == 1) ? &intvar1 : &intvar2;
```

variable `intvar2` turn's `NULL`, but that's not true. The only variable which is modified is `pointer` and is pointing to variable `intvar1`.